# Opening ports on a remote DB server

Tags: mysql, iptables, database, rhel6, database-administration

I'm running a RHEL7 box, running MySQL-5.7.11 and I'm simply trying to allow remote connections...

I followed the documentation [here](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux_OpenStack_Platform/3/html/Installation_and_Configuration_Guide/Configuring_the_Firewall3.html) on opening a port and have done so successfully.

When I run `iptables -nL | grep 3306` it outputs:

`ACCEPT     tcp  --  0.0.0.0/0            0.0.0.0/0            multiport dports 3306`

---

When I try and connect to it `mysql -h xxx-xxx-xxxx -u 'username' -pxxxxx` I get:

`Host 'xxx-xxx-xxxx' is not allowed to connect to this MySQL server`

Even though I have allowed permissions to that user for the entire database.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Network-level issues are not the problem here. You solved those with your iptables rule. Your MySQL grant **is** a problem, though.

MySQL grants have three parts you need to consider:

1. username
2. password
3. host you're connecting from

It looks like you have #1 and #2 sorted out. #3 is still a problem though. Ensure that your grant allows your user to connect from `Host 'xxx-xxx-xxxx'`.

Comment: Yea I gave the user @ host * privs thats why I'm confused.

Comment: Please edit your question and post the *exact* `GRANT` statement you used to create this user.

Comment: okay wow I did the grant via Navicat (GUI), I rant the grant via CMDLINE and it works now. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Lesson learned: CLI is always better. :)